# HTML/CSS/JS beginner errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

These are working in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HJrD/) that [andi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1165535/andi) posted on the answer to my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278184/how-do-i-make-a-hover-pseudoclass-affect-the-parent-element). I'm stumped as to what I've missed that it isn't working in the browser. I know this is going to be a very simple fix. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="blackwrap">
    <header class="blackbar">
        <h2>Before he knew it, he couldn't see a thing.</h2>
        <h4>He fumbled around for the <a id="flash">flashlight</a> on his phone.</h4>
    </header>
</div> <!-- .blackwrap-->    

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.blackbar {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
.blackbar.lit {
    background:yellow;
    color:black;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#flash").on("mouseover", function(){
    $(".blackbar").addClass("lit");
}).on("mouseout", function(){
    $(".blackbar").removeClass("lit")
});
```

Comment: code is working fine. Make sure scripts are loaded properly.

Comment: So what's the problem, exactly? The jsfiddle seems to work fine. Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: check with inspect element with chrome browser identify the errors and post it here

Comment: The fiddle does not work for me in IE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be, you are running the Jquery include code in your local machine with using the `file://` protocol.

So on your local machine use

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

change to this on the server

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

at the server, it will be `http:` or `https:` , so server will automatically select the corresponding one.

Answer (score 2):

your jquery is not loaded properly use **http:** in src as below:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This assumes that the OP is testing by using a `file:///` URI for the page. It is possible that is the case, but the question doesn't state that.

Comment: yes this is the appropriate reason that the code is not running

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple fix in the cdn link to jquery you should make a http call

instead of this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

change it to this

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is if you dont keep http the browser thinks it is a local file in your pc.

[image]